# Uso de while em uma Thread no Android(runOnUiThread)

Tags: android

Olá, galera estou tendo o seguinte problema preciso gerenciar uma animação. A qual muda com o tempo, e para isso fiz o seguinte código:

```
public void HandleAnimator(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        boolean pass1 = true;
        boolean pass2 = true;
        boolean pass3 = true;
        boolean pass4 = true;
        boolean pass5 = true;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    SetAnimator(1); //Animação inicial

                    while(mCountDonwTime.getmTime()!=0) {
                        if(mCountDonwTime.getmTime()<80000 && pass2){
                            SetAnimator(2);
                            pass3 = false;
                        }
                        if(mCountDonwTime.getmTime() < 60000 && pass3){
                            SetAnimator(3);
                            pass4 = false;
                        }
                        if(mCountDonwTime.getmTime() < 40000 && pass4){
                            SetAnimator(4);
                            pass4 = false;
                        }
                        if(mCountDonwTime.getmTime() < 20000  && pass5){
                            SetAnimator(5);
                            pass5 = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

public void SetAnimator(int animacao){

    switch(animacao){
        case 1:
            im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
            break;
        case 2:
            im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animationb);
            break;
        case 3:
            im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animationc);
            break;
        case 4:
            im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animationd);
            break;
        case 5:
            im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animatione);
            break;
    }

    AnimationDrawable Animation = (AnimationDrawable) im.getBackground();
    Animation.start();
}
```

Quando uso esse while dentro da estrutura dessa thread, há um tipo de sobrecarga no processador do device. Logo não sei de que outra forma poderia fazer pra controlar essas animações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rode somente a chamada a `SetAnimator()` no thread de UI usando `runOnUiThread()`, e o loop em si no thread que você criou. Se rodar o loop inteiro no thread de UI como está fazendo vai dar problema mesmo.

Comment: consegui resolver aqui com uma solução alternativa mas valeu =)